# Low-pass filter for IMU accelerometer data

Tags: low-pass, accelerometer, imu

I am using Labview to get data from an IMU and I need to filter the data since it is noisy.

I am using a low-pass filter but the filtered data is less than the measured data (the acceleration was 10 and it becomes 2).

Does anyone know the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Please add more details. Perhaps a screen shot. The equations used for filtering etc. A plot of the signal before and after filtering. There is too little info in the question now. Please add details by using the [edit] button.

Comment: Noisy data would likely contain spikes well beyond meaningful values.  On the other hand, it's quite easy for a filtering attempt to accidentally result in scaling (or even to destroy the data entirely).  Try things with the sensor unmoving and placed carefully level (maybe even collect data for a timed period and throw out the start/end when you were hitting a key).  In that case you should fairly clearly see gravity hopefully aligned with on axis, and in working with the data sheet be able to get a correct answer.

Comment: depending on the level of filtering, maybe you need to wait longer for the filter to settle on the actual average value.